# No wsdl file generated while creating WebService in a JEE project

Tags: eclipse, web-services, jakarta-ee, apache-axis

I have a java class which contains a default constructor and custom constructor + 3 methods and i want to make it as a webservice so i did a right click on it > web services > create web service and i followed the instructions but when I start runing my project and go to service from the axis2 page and click on my service the wsdl file doesn't show here is a screen shot for the result 
[image]

please if you want any extra info to help me ask for it because i don't know where can be the problem

Comment: What do you see if you display the page source?

Comment: which page source ?